# Using Conditionals in Title Format

Tags: conditional, channels, titles

I've got a new channel for Authors where there are 3 fields:

firstName
middleName
lastName

and I'm using these fields to generate the Title of the channel entry. However I would like to add a conditional around middleName so that it isn't used if empty and I can avoid have double space between first and last name.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title field supports ternary syntax conditionals. You could do that like this:

`{firstName} {middleName|length ? middleName ~ ' '}{lastName}`

That says "if middleName has length, print it out, and append a space with `~`.

Also part of the ternary syntax is the "else" statement, which looks like the below. This is the code I use for most of my asset alt texts for accessibility.

`{{ asset.assetAltText|length ? asset.assetAltText : asset.title }}`

If asset.assetAltText has a length, use that. Otherwise use the asset title as the alt text

Comment: Excellent, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the [join](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/join.html) filter in these fields? If so, something like this may be a little cleaner:

```
{{ [object.firstName, object.middleName, object.lastName] | join(' ') }}
```